# How to add a 2nd y-axis for a density plot superimposed on a histogram in R?

Tags: r, histogram, density-plot

I have a histogram shown below, and I have added 2 density plots on top of that. It corresponds to the 2 classes that make up the data.

[image: histogram]
I want to add a 2nd y-axis on the right, but having same height as the 1st y-axis, so that the height of the density plots do not look so small. **The relative heights of the 2 density plots must to directly comparable, such that their combined area is 1**

Comment: Downvoting for no code and no data.

Comment: You could use `doubleYScale` from 'latticeExtra' package. See this [link](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/#doubleYScale&theme=default) for further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
z <- rnorm(100,.3,.2)
hist(z, xlab="", ylab="", main="", yaxt="n")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(density(z), xlab="", ylab="", main="", xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
axis(2, ...) # plug in the relevant values for `at` and `labels`
axis(4, ...) # plug in the relevant values for `at` and `labels`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way for me to make the relative heights of the density plots to be directly comparable. Remember I have 2 density plots here for the 2 classes of data that make up the histogram. Also, how do I find out the density values, i.e. what should the value of the 2nd y-axis be?

Comment: You could do something like `max(density(z)$y)` to get an upper limit for each density and then specify the axes accordingly. For two densities, you would obviously do this separately for each and just repeat the `plot(density(z), ...)` bit for the second density.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `ggplot2` you can use `geom_density(aes(y=..scaled..))` and `geom_histogram(aes(y = ..ndensity))` to scale similarly

eg

```
x <- rnorm(400, 10, 5)
y <- rnorm(400, -10, 5)
dd <- rbind(data.frame(value = x, id = 'x'), data.frame(value = y, id = 'y'))
ggplot(dd, aes(x=value)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..ndensity..)) + 
  geom_density(aes(colour = id, y = ..scaled..))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I made a mistake in my original question. The total area of the 2 density plots should equal 1, so that they are directly comparable. Since the histogram shows the whole data, but the 2 density plots show the data for 1 class, their height should probably be smaller too.

In your plot, I only see 1 axis. I want an 2nd y-axis on the right showing the density.